# Can the question list show if a question is answered or commented by you

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface, user-experience, question-lists

When we see any question, can we have a tag to identify if the question is answered or commented by you without opening the detail of question. Something like this in image below: See the top right corner where two boxes says "You Answered" Or "You Commented"

[image]

Comment: Why? You can see your comments and your answers easily from your own personal SO page

Comment: Yeah, In that way, you don't need to go to personal page to check that. Suppose  you are browsing list of question and you don't know whether you already have answered or commented, you may end up revisiting the same question. This will help to avoid user to revisit the question.

Comment: I like this idea. I'm not convinced they will put resources into developing it. I'm sure someone could write a script to do this.

Comment: 1) comments aren't meant to persist or to hold information of key importance and so aren't important enough for this feature. 2) This would only be needed for answers if questions typically held many answers, too many to easily skim through, and this is rarely the case. I vote against this proposal.

Comment: The similar question was asked on (migrated to) Meta.SE  nine years ago, still no response: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25857/highlighting-questions-in-which-i-have-already-posted-or-commented

Comment: @Shahid Most browsers will show links you've clicked on before in a different color. It isn't quite as good as what you're suggesting, but it's something

Comment: What about adding "You Edited" and "You Voted" as well? ;)

Comment: @Cœur, Yeah why not :). For "You Voted", they already have indicator. It makes the voting button in different color if you have voted. "You Editied" - Yes they can add that as well.

Comment: @Shahid OK, small confusion: your screenshot is of the kind we see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c, and there aren't voting buttons on such pages.

Comment: @Cœur. You are correct. So now I support your both suggestion :) .

Comment: Thanks @Robert for the edit. It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like this idea. It's handy when browsing the front page or your favourite tags.

**However:**

I'm not convinced the network will put or should put resources into developing it.

I'm sure someone could write a script to do this.

Comment: The problem with creating a userscript here is that it has load those question pages, so users will get hit with a rate limit quickly especially if they are displaying 30/50 posts per page. It's just not viable.

Comment: @SamuelLiew: API would work a ton better for the purpose: if you have 50 questions displayed and an average of 5 answers each, [3 API calls](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions) would return all you need, and the API has good support for backoff.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm not sure where you're getting 3 API calls. If you want to check only if you are the most recent editor (i.e. all info requested above, except checking for having edited at any time, and assuming that "voted" doesn't include voted to close), then it's 1 API call which fetches all questions and answers (when fetching questions you can get all answers on each question at the same time). If you want to check all revisions, then it's 3 additional API calls (3x 100 posts). If you want to check for close-votes, it's 50 additional API calls (that route doesn't permit multiple IDs).

Comment: @Makyen: Editing and voting weren't in view, only answering and commenting. Getting all 250 answers from a page of 50 questions with 5 answers each would take 3 API calls, because of the 100-item paging limit. (More typical results would usually fit in a single call, of course: 5/Q is pretty high.) Throwing comments into the mix complicates things, since there can be an awful lot more comments on some questions. Still, often enough [one additional call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-questions) would do the job, although it could easily balloon pretty far.

Comment: @NathanTuggy With [1 API call](//api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids) you can get up to 100 questions, including all comments on all of the questions, all answers on all questions, all comments on all of those answers, and with an auth token, the user's up- and down-votes on all of those Q & A. If you're wanting the [revisions](//api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids), then you need to request them for each post, but up to 100 per request, so (50 + 5*50)/100 = 3 API requests. Close-votes/flags don't have a bulk request method. Thus, it's 1 request per question, so 50 requests.

Comment: @Makyen: Well, [no, paging does not work that way](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging). You're limited to 100 results per page, so 100 answers per page, so 3 calls for 250 answers. Comments separate. [I can't get /questions/{ids} to give me answers and comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=374494&filter=default&site=meta.stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've *done it*, in more than one project. It *definitely* works this way. You need to use a [non-default `filter`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters), or you don't get answers or comments. Click the "[edit]" at the top right where you're entering the example request to edit the filter. For a question you get *all* information for that question, including all of the information for the question's answers as a *single* response. Thus, even if you're asking for 100 questions, each of which has 100 answers, it's still 1 API call to get all 100 questions with 10,000 answers.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Try [this URL](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/374494?site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!gCWg*mQ9tXF0NHeTLZCDYJT1-qCltMN2Mbs) or enter in the console `$.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/374494?site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!gCWg*mQ9tXF0NHeTLZCDYJT1-qCltMN2Mbs').then(response => console.log(response));` to see it as an Object that you can explore.

Answer (score 5):

And I disagree with my esteemed colleague, Yvette. As stated in *comments* above:

- Comments aren't meant to persist or to hold information of lasting value, and so the utility of marking a question as holding your comment is of limited value. Not only that, but you can easily search for your comments in your own personal SO page's activity section. It's easy to use and very informative
- The utility of your suggestion for questions would be high if most questions held many answers, say greater than 5 or 6. Any less than that and it is trivial to quickly scan to see if your answer is present. I think that this is one reason for personal avatar images, so that it is easy and even trivial to scan for our own questions and answers.

So in sum, I vote "no" to your suggested change -- But ¡Viva la democracia!

Comment: Well. What I am trying to explain here is to avoid going to personal page or open the question to see if I have answered or commented. Just by looking at the question, you know if you have visited it before.  So it doesn't matter if comment is not important or whether the question has multiple answers. The whole idea is to avoid revisiting the same question.